# How to retrieve data from mongoDB and show it inside in dialogflow using inline editor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dialogflow-es, mongodb-atlas, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

i am trying to get the saved data from mongoDB atlas and show it inside the dialogflow chatbot but it keep telling me that webhook deadline exceeded this is my code to get the data if anyone knows how to solve it please let me know:

```
function mongoHandler(agent){
        var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb+srv://"my mongoDB atlas credentials"@cluster0.yhuli.mongodb.net";

MongoClient.connect(url,{useUnifiedTopology: true},function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("FitbitDB");
  var query = { UniqueId: "9657CQ"};
  dbo.collection("fitbit").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var x =result[0].FirstName;
    console.log(x);
    agent.add("Hello"+x);
    db.close();
  });
});
    agent.add(`Mongo connected`);// this single line code works but when i try to define x here     it's not working
}

    
      let intentMap = new Map();
    
      intentMap.set('getMongo', mongoHandler);
      agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });
```

Comment: use async/await or .then or use callback for `find query`

Comment: is there a sample code ? i can refer to ?

Comment: this code works fine on my local machine but when i paste this same code inside the dialogflow it's not working , i really don't kow how to modify it for dialoglow

Comment: I don't know what is the dialogflow  exactly but you can allow access from anywhere from MongoDB Atlas with `0.0.0.0/0`, maybe the problem is about mongodb atlas

Comment: i already did that still not working

Comment: This code works fine on my local machine but not on dialogflow inline editior 